# Option box displayed using ng-options is empty

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to display a simple option box in angularjs using `ng-options` attribute as,

```
<select ng-options="item for item in allItems">
```

Surprisingly, this simple example doesn't show options. I am sorry, it looks like a simple error but i am not able to catch it.

Code is at, [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/24513/).

I can see in browser console, the error as,

```
Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myApp' is not available!
```

How does the variable `myApp` get considered when i had namespaced my app as `skAngApp`?

Comment: Where is you module "myApp" because the error is related to myApp first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you created the fiddle 'myApp' was being defined as the ng-app in the html body. If you click on HTML within your jsfiddle you'll see the body tag.

Working example below.

```
<div ng-controller="appCtrl">
   {{allItems}}
    <select ng-options="o as o for o in allItems" ng-model="item"></select>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/24515/

Answer (score 1):

[image: jsFiddle options]
Change Body Tag with the real name of the App